# How to open div slowly using animation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone help how to slowly open div to his full size;

What i have:

## rules div with HEIGHT 200px and overflow-y:hidden.

when press button #showall i need slowly make #rules height to his 100% !!

what i tried:

```
$("#showall").click(function(){
      $( "#rules" ).animate({
      height: "+=100px"
   }, 5000, function() {
      // Animation complete.
});
```

in my example height; +=100px - its work normally, but if i change to height: "100%" its open div FAST without Animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Slidedown:

```
$("#showall").click(function(){
  $( "#rules" ).slideDown( 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Try this new solution:

```
$this= $("#rules");
 var currentHeight =  $this.height();
        autoHeight = $this.css('height', 'auto').height()
        $this.data('height', currentHeight)
             .height(currentHeight).animate({
                                        height: autoHeight},
                                        200,
                                        function() { $(this).addClass('open'); });
```

Comment: something wrong.. not working..its not opening div to his full size. i repeat. #showall has css properties height:200px; overflow-y:hidden; i need to open to full size (100%); it could be 598px or 400px or etc.